# Determinant of a matrix will all off-diagonal elements equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider matrices of the following form:
\begin{bmatrix} a & x & \cdots \\ 
x & b & x &\cdots \\
\vdots & x & c &\cdots \\ 
 & \vdots & x & \ddots & \\ \end{bmatrix}
where all $x$ are the same scalar. Is there anything that can be done to calculate the determinant easily? Obviously if $$x=a=b=c=\cdots $$ then the matrix is singular and the determinant is zero. Assume this is not the case.

Do they have any other interesting properties?

Comment: ...I'm wondering whether there's a factoring of this matrix that can use the multiplicative property of determinants... hmm...@JPJanet

Comment: If you can see any factoring at all I'd happily take it. I struggle to work with a matrix of "all ones" .  It's $(ONES - I)x + v$ but that doesn't seem to help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(a,b,\ldots)-xI$ and let $e$ be the all-one vector. Then your matrix is equal to $D+xee^T$. As a [consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) of the Sherman-Morrison formula, we have
$$
\det(D+xee^T)
=\det(D)+xe^T\operatorname{adj}(D)e
=\prod_{j=1}^nd_{jj}+x\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\ne i}d_{jj}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I had looked at Sherman-Morrison but I wasn't clicking that ee^T was what I needed.